POWER BI How to compare value from cell "A" with cell "B" and only if cell "A" has a date added will my "Card" count value of cell "B"
Note: I am a newbie.
I have a Card which shows the total number of containers shipped in the year, however I want it to only show the number of containers which have actually packed. My table also shows upcoming containers which need to pack and If the containers are not packed yet we do not put a date in the "DATE PACKED" Column. I need a way to read if Column A(Date Packed) is blank then the Card will not count the cell in Column B(No. Of Containers).



Date Packed
No. Of Containers




02/04/2024
10


05/04/2024
12


12/04/2024
10



24



I want Card to = 32 and not 56
The quick fix option I is to add a new column and separate the packed with the not packed but I am trying to minimize the number of columns on my worksheet as the whole one is already complex and would like to avoid extra edits.

Not familiar with POWERBI, but you could use something like =SUM(FILTER(B2:B5 , A2:A5<>"")); where B2:B5 is your No of Containers, and A2:A5 is your date packed.

Here is the formula that you can use:
=SUMIFS(your_no_of_containers_cell_range,your_date_packed_cell_range,"<>")


I did the same except checked col A to be greater than 1...
